# Cursor returns Multiple Rows & Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL is limited and I have inherited the schema so please go easy!

[image]

The upper tables are populated, the lower section is to be completed.
The customer wants a simple reference, C_SCAFFOLD_DOMAIN_COMBO, for every C_SEQUENCE_RESULT of the same TYPE having the same C_PROTEIN_REGIONs (only ever two) of the same REGION_NAME.

My intention is to read each C_SEQUENCE_RESULT getting the (2) C_PROTEIN_REGION.SEQUENCEs with their REGION_NAME using a cursor.

I can then check if they are referenced by a C_SCAFFOLD_DOMAIN_COMBO already.

If so, then simply add the correct C_SCAFFOLD_DOMAIN_NAME FK to C_SEQUENCE_RESULT.

If not, create a new C_SCAFFOLD_DOMAIN_NAME entry with the appropriate C_PROTEIN_REGION refs and add the FK to C_SEQUENCE_RESULT.

My SQL query returns two results for each C_SEQUENCE_RESULT e.g.

REGION_NAME------SEQUENCE

Loop 1------ABCDEFG

Loop 2------HIJKLMN

Running as a simple query and can INSERT INTO a temp table and get the values.  As a cursor I don’t seem to be able.

How can I read the data returned above using a cursor?

Thanks

Comment: Generally if you want to use a Cursor then something has gone wrong. Cursors are an iterative task, which SQL Server does not do well. SQL Server, instead, excels at set based processes and you should be aiming to use a set based approach. Unfortunately we have very little to help you with your goal here, basically just an idea and then you effectively ask  "how do I use a Cursor?" Instead, show us your sample data (as formatted `text` or DDL and DML statement; **not** an image as they are almost useless to us), and expected results. If you've made attempts, share those too please. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have swerved the problem by 'splitting' the SQL cursor query over the two (and only two) REGION_NAMEs in the data.  I run the cursor using one value then query using the second value.

I am sure that someone with suitable experience could solve this 'properly' - it's just beyond my ken!